# Azure AD SSO Integration with ServiceNow not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, servicenow

I was trying to implement SSO(Single Sign On) on my Servicenow instance using AzureActiveDirectory. I followed the tutorial at [Tutorial Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/saas-apps/servicenow-tutorial). I have configured necessary plugins on servicenow account for enabling SSO and created the Enterprise Application on Azure AD portal as well. However, when I test the configuration from Servicenow Multi-SSO Integration Provider page, I get a positive result, but once I actually login as a external user from Servicenow Login screen, I get invalid credentials as output.
Also, The external login page is not of microsoft login but some other IDP provider name. Is this is what is expected or not ?
I am attaching my configuration for both servicenow and AzureApp.

[image: Azure AD config]
 [image: ServiceNow Config:]
[image: Login screen :]